# Bitnami LAMP stack not working 2nd time

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I installed lamp for web development. I tested it. writing localhost/phpmyadmin/ it works.
next time I turned on my laptop. localhost/phpmyadmin/ is not  working. Is there anything special we need to do with lamp? as Wamp was simple. 
the error says web page not available whereas, i have it isntalled in a directory. Will be  happy to good comments please

Answer (score 0):

The reason was, We need to start servers for apache and mysql to enable them via domain (localhost) or port (8080 default). 
if using LAMP, go to the directory for lamp, find "manager-linux" "Manage servers" restart all. then go for browser and type localhost/

When using WAMP, go down to task task bar, right click wamp icon and select restart/start servers

Enjoy